# Please help me understand the method used for solving Linear homogeneous and non-homogeneous recursive functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, recurrence-relations

> f(n)=2*f(n-1)+2^n

I just want to make it clear I can solve the question by following the rules, my doubts in using the usual method are

1. Why do we guess the solution $f(n)=k^{n}$ rather than some polynomial?
2. After finding the roots how do the linear combination of the solution of characteristic equation is equal to $f(n)$?
3. Similarly, what is the logic behind the guessing of the particular solution?

Comment: If $S$ denotes the shift operator, this is $Sf(n)=f(n+1)$, and you write the homogneous equation as $P(S)f=0$ for some polynomial $P$ with constant coefficients, then you can factor the polynomial and get an equation like $\prod_{i=1}^n(S-r_i)f=0$. Now you can see that if $f$ satisfies at least one of the equations $(S-r_i)f=0$, then it also satisfies the previous one. The solution of $(S-r_i)f=0$ is the sequence $f(n)=Ar_i^{n}$.

Comment: 1) The solution of $f(n)=rf(n-1)$ is obviously $f(n)=Ar^n$ for $A$ arbitrary – just think about it. 2) is a word salad – I can't parse what you have written. 3) When the inhomogeneous term is $c^n$, there's a particular solution of the form $Bc^n$ – except when that's also a solution of the homogeneous equation, as it is here. Then you have to multiply by an appropriate power of $n$. But there have been dozens of questions on this site about solving this kind of recurrence. Have a search!

Comment: Would you like to engage with the comments and answers that have been posted, 173379?

Comment: Are you still here, 173379?

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave is a type of linear **non**-homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficients usually written in the form
$$
a_{n} - 2 \cdot a_{n-1} = 2^{n} \text{ for } n \geq 1, \tag{1}
$$
with initial condition $a_{0} = C$. Solution is of the form
$$
a_{n} = z_{n} + b_{n},
$$
where $z_{n}$ is the solution of the associated homogeneous recurrence relation in this case
$$
a_{n} - 2 \cdot a_{n-1} = 0
$$
with associated characteristic equation in this case $x - 2 = 0$ and solution $z_{n} = C \cdot 2^{n}$. When function on the right hand side of Equation (1) is of the form $\alpha^{n}$ and when $\alpha$ is the root of the characteristic equation with multiplicity $s$, the guess for the particular solution is of the form
$$
b_{n} = n^{s} \cdot \alpha^{n}.
$$
In your example $b_{n} = n \cdot 2^{n}$ and final solution of (1) is
$$
a_{n} = C \cdot 2^{n} + n \cdot 2^{n}.
$$
To see why this works, you need to prove some propositions, for example the following. Proposition: Let $a_{n} = c_{1} a_{n-1} + ... + c_{k} a_{n-k} + f(n)$ be a linear non-homogeneous recurrence and assume the sequence $b_{n}$ satisfies the recurrence. Then another sequence $a_{n}$ satisfies the non-homogeneous recurrence if and only if $z_{n} = a_{n} - b_{n}$ is also a sequence that satisfies the associated homogeneous recurrence. You can find the proof [here](http://nms.lu.lv/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/21-linear-recurrences.pdf).

Another approach is to use generating functions. Let 
$$
G(x) = a_{0} + a_{1} x + ... + a_{n} x^{n} + ... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n}
$$
be the generating function for the sequence $a_{n}$. Then
\begin{align*} 
G(x) &= C + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (2\cdot a_{n-1} + 2^{n}) x^{n} \\
&= C + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n-1}x^{n} + \sum_{n=1}^{n}(2x)^{n} \\
&= C + 2 x (a_{0} + a_{1}x + a_{2}a^{2} + ...) + 
2x(1 + (2x)^{1} + (2x)^{2} + (2x)^{3} + ...) \\
&= C + 2 x \cdot G(x) + 2x \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 2x}
\end{align*}
which we can solve for $G(x)$
\begin{align*} 
G(x) &- 2x\cdot G(x) = C + 2x \frac{1}{1 - 2x} \\
G(x) &= C \frac{1}{1-2x} + 2x \frac{1}{(1-2x)^{2}} \\
G(x) &= 
C (1 + (2x) + (2x)^{2} + ... + (2x)^{n} + ...) + \\
   &  + 2x (1 + 2(2x) + 3(2x)^{2} + ... + n(2x)^{n-1} + ...)
\end{align*}
and from this we see the coefficient of $x^{n}$ is 
$$
a_{n} = C \cdot 2^{n} + n \cdot 2^{n}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For your example
$$f_n=2f_{n-1}+2^n$$ let $f_n=2^n g_n$ to end with
$$g_n=2g_{n-1}+1$$